# When to use super or override in methods when you extend from a class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Hi I'm new to java and I currently have two classes(useForce and Attack) that are working fine but these two classes share a lot of code.To reduce duplicated code I extended use Force class from Attack class but I'm not sure how to modify the code?

For example in my attack.java

```
public class Attack extends SWAffordance implements SWActionInterface {
         some code here...

@Override
public boolean canDo(SWActor a) {
    SWEntityInterface target = this.getTarget();
    return !a.isDead() && target.getHitpoints()>0;
}

   @Override
public void act(SWActor a) {
    SWEntityInterface target = this.getTarget();
    boolean targetIsActor = target instanceof SWActor;
    SWActor targetActor = null;
    int energyForAttackWithWeapon = 1;//the amount of energy required to attack with a weapon

    if (targetIsActor) {
        targetActor = (SWActor) target;
    }
```

But the same two methods in my useForce.java is

```
public class UseForce extends Attack {
     some code here....

@Override
public boolean canDo(SWActor a) {
    return a.getForcepoints()>=minUsePoints;
}

@Override
public void act(SWActor a) {
    SWEntityInterface target = this.getTarget();
    boolean targetIsActor = target instanceof SWActor;
    SWActor targetActor = null;
    int energyForForceAttack = 2;//the amount of energy required to use force

    if (targetIsActor) {
        targetActor = (SWActor) target;
    }
```

As you can see these two share many similar lines of code in act method except in  Attack.java int energyForAttackWithWeapon = 1 whereas in useForce int energyforAttackWithWeapon=2...
How do I use super or override to reduce the lines of duplicated code?Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:If I use a thirdparty class to extract the duplicated code, how do I do it because Attack already extends from SWAffordance?

Comment: You could use a third method extracting the duplicate code in the parent and let it be called by both the child and the parent implementations.

Comment: But my attack.java already extends from SWAffordance.And one class can't extend from two classes?

Comment: Useforce extends Attack so you could define a method in Attack that could be used by both classes

Comment: ‘target instanceof SWActoe’ will be always ‘true’ in your ‘act()’ method

Answer (score 0):

[The template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) could help to solve your duplication issue.
It allows to define a common algorithm in a base class while leaving the subclasses to custom some parts of the algorithm.

So define both common concrete operations and custom operations to define by subclasses in an abstract class : `AbstractAttack`.

```
public abstract class AbstractAttack extends SWAffordance implements SWActionInterface {

    public abstract int getEnergyForAttack();
    public abstract boolean canDo(SWActor a);

    public void act(SWActor a) {
        SWEntityInterface target = this.getTarget();
        boolean targetIsActor = target instanceof SWActor;
        SWActor targetActor = null;
        int energyForAttack = getEnergyForAttack();
        ... // use  energyForAttack 
        if (targetIsActor) {
            targetActor = (SWActor) target;
        }
    }


}
```

Now `Attack` and Other subclasses inherit from `AbstractAttack` to benefit from concrete operations and also implement theirs own specificities :

```
public class DefaultAttack extends AbstractAttack  {

   @Override
   public boolean canDo(SWActor a) {
       SWEntityInterface target = this.getTarget();
       return !a.isDead() && target.getHitpoints()>0;
   }

   @Override
   public int getEnergyForAttack(){
        return 1;
   }
}

public class UseForce extends AbstractAttack  {

   @Override
   public boolean canDo(SWActor a) {
      return a.getForcepoints()>=minUsePoints;
  }

   @Override
   public int getEnergyForAttack(){
       return 2;
   }
}
```